# JPEG size as byte array to Web API

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to send a jpeg as a byte array from a phone to a Web API.  Initally, the image captured by the phone is about 2mb with dimensions of 2000x3500, so I have scaled it down to roughly 300x500 dimensions, which brings the image size down to about 135k.

The application still takes about 10 seconds or so to send that to the Web API via the code below if not using WiFi, and sometimes it just fails (due to the size I believe, or a timeout somewhere).

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Send", msg);
```

Is there any way for me to compress a jpeg so that I can send it to a WebAPI from a phone without making it tiny?

I am transferring some other information along with the byte array in the object, such as user id, etc.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: As if jpeg is already a compressed format. You win nearly nothing if you re-compress it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any way to make the transfer quicker.  There are two options for Windows Phone.  Either implement a "sending" notification and hold the UI... however this does not stop them from quitting the app.

The BackgroundUploader class is another method, but only works with Windows Phone 8.1 and you can only upload files, not objects;  http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounduploader.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you can enable buffering in the web api. That might help you speedup the upload. The interface that is used to enable buffering in web API is [IHostBufferPolicySelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.hosting.ihostbufferpolicyselector%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

I haven't tried that but this [link](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/) might help you.